# Mobile Safari -webkit-gradient iOS5/6 inconsistency

Tags: css, ios6, mobile-safari

I've noticed an inconsistency in the way Mobile Safari on iOS5 and iOS6 handles -webkit-radial-gradient that I'd like to rectify in a webapp.

Take the following example:

```
div {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: black;
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center center, circle cover, rgba(255,255,255,1), rgba(0,0,0,0) 75%);
    position:absolute;
}
```

applied to

```
<div>&nbsp;</div>
```

Viewable/editable: http://jsfiddle.net/kJ8z3/3/
For mobile devices: http://fiddle.jshell.net/kJ8z3/3/show/

For some reason, the gradient is "stronger" on iOS6.

- [iOS6 screenshot](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/93587851/Photo%20Oct%2019%2C%203%2031%2015%20PM.png) (iPad 2, WebKit 536.26)
- [iOS5 screenshot](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/93587851/Photo%20Oct%2019%2C%203%2031%2019%20PM.png) (iPad 1, WebKit 534.46)

An updated version of Google Chrome (WebKit 537.4) or Safari (Webkit 534.57.2) on a desktop produces a gradient more-similar to iOS5, so it's probably not directly a WebKit issue.

Both devices report 32-bit color depth (screen.colorDepth), however the gradient from iOS5 seems to show artifacts of banding indicative or a lower color depth. Google Chrome reports 32-bit depth, but has more banding than Desktop Safari, which only reports 24-bit color depth.

Any idea what's going on? Or more importantly from a practical standpoint, how I can reconcile the difference between the two? I'd like an identically rendered radial gradient with alpha transparency fading from white to transparent.

Comment: Interestingly, I tried this in the iOS Simulator using iOS 6 (Build 10A403) and the results matched iOS 5. The WebKit version is the same 536.26. http://i.imgur.com/g8KKC.png

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like it "works" across the board. It's just a matter of how well it works between the OS,device,etc. To help cure banding issues in Photoshop, adding a third, sometimes 5th color to a gradient helps the visual result quite a bit. It cuts down the amount of color transitions the program is responsible (it does have to calculate them all...).

Anyway, I added a third color to your gradient, and it tightened things up.
http://fiddle.jshell.net/8U46E/

This site may help a bit, if you're not a Photoshop guy/gal: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/